# Make a div box center bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="col-md-6"> <h1>however I am working on the way you can see the attached file is scanned</h1><p>may I ask for your time pe daal Dena hill the other day and I am working on it and I am working on it and I am working on it and it was best which was thinking the other side me to do</p></div>
```

I want to make this col-md-6 div in a centre of a row.

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom class on your div and try this:

```
.custom-class {
     float: none;
     margin: auto 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way without using custom class css.

Comment: You can use `col-md-6` but it will affect all divs that has `col-md-6` as their class